# C fork loop to exec infinite commands (urandom/tail on an active file)

Tags: c, unix, pipe, exec, execvp

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of a pipe in a unix (OSX) shell (like bash) with C.
I have no problem to handle a command which is not infinite (for example: `ls | wc -c`).

But as you can imagine, I have an issue, I can't handle an infinite command, for instance: `base64 /dev/urandom" | head -c 1000`.
The output of this command is immediately the first 1000 characters of urandom.

My function just wait the end of the urandom which is infite... So, I need to kill with "CTRL + C" the process (and handle the signal to just the child and not my function) to print the first 1000 character.

My function to execute all the pipes:

```
#define READ_END        0
#define WRITE_END       1


void    exec_pipes(char ***argv)
{
    int   p[2];
    int   fd_save = 0;

    while (*argv)
    {
        pipe(p);
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            dup2(fd_save, STDIN_FILENO);
            if (*(argv + 1))
                dup2(p[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(p[READ_END]);
            execvp(**argv, *argv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
            fd_save = p[READ_END];
            close(p[WRITE_END]);
            (*argv)++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can check my entire code with the main :
https://www.onlinegdb.com/Hkbjd3WOz

Thanks in advance.

Comment: regarding: `
void    exec_pipes(char ***argv)`  please read: `[3star programer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: the posted code fails to compile.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce/debug the problem.

Comment: Please do not post links to code.  Rather, post the code as part of the question

Comment: the function 'pipe()' can fail.  The code should be checking the returned status

Comment: the function 'fork()' can fail. So the posted code should be checking for such a failure.

Comment: the function 'execvp()' (when successful) never returns.  So the first statement after the call to that function should be: `perror( "execve failed" );`

Comment: the linked code has the header file: `stdio.h` included 3 times, WHY?

Comment: the posted code will not pipe the output of the first command `base64` into the input of the second command `head`  Amongst other problems, each iteration of the `while()` loop is generating a whole new pipe.  Suggest the parent process know do no processing of the pipes.  Suggest only create a single pipe.  Suggest the first command (in the child process) only modify `stdout`.  Suggest the second command (in the child process) only modify `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not, you don't.  When a reading process just finishes, it closes the reading side of the pipe, and so the writer is not allowed to write anymore to the pipe, and gets an error `EPIPE` (cannot write to pipe) from the system.

For this to ocurr, no process has to have it open for reading, because the kernel counts the number of reading and writing processes, and will not give this error while at least one process left it open for reading (this means the first process in the chain has to close the read file descriptor of the pipe, if it is not going to read from it)

Then, you have to close the descriptor not used (it depends if you want the parent to be the writer or the reader) IN THE PARENT AND CHILD, and `dup2(2)` the other descriptor (again, IN THE PARENT AND CHILD) to file descriptor `0` (in) or `1` (out).  (first to say, I've changed your `/dev/urandom` example by a call to the `yes` command, because it's standard in all unix flavours, and produces also infinite output)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *writer_program = "yes";
char *argv_writer[] = {
    "yes", "yes", NULL,
};
char *reader_program = "head";
char *argv_reader[] = {
    "head", "-c", "10", NULL,
};

int main()
{
    int pipe_fds[2];
    int res;

    pipe(pipe_fds);
    if ((res = fork()) < 0) {     /* PLEASE, CHECK FOR ERRORS. */
        perror("fork");
    } else if (res == 0) {        /* child process, ACTING AS WRITER */
        close(pipe_fds[0]);       /* close writing part of pipe */
        dup2(pipe_fds[1], 1);     /* dup2 reading part as stdin */
        execvp(writer_program, argv_writer);
        perror("execvp");         /* PLEASE, CHECK FOR ERRORS. */
    } else {                      /* parent process, ACTING AS A READER */
        close(pipe_fds[1]);       /* just the opposite */
        dup2(pipe_fds[0], 0);
        execvp(reader_program, argv_reader);
        perror("execvp");         /* PLEASE, CHECK FOR ERRORS. */
    }
    /* BOTH, THIS IS REACHED IN CASE OF FAILURE (fork fails, or any
     * of the exec(2) calls  fail. */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

## EDIT

Below is a complete example with a pipeline chain equivalent to the next:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom ibs=1024 | base64 | head -n 150 | sort -r | pr
```

in this case, the first program to die is `head`, as you wanted, and every program dies behind it.  The parent program is waiting for all his children to die, and every system call has been wrapped, so you get a trace of execution through stderr, to see what happens.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define F(fmt) "[pid=%d]:"__FILE__":%d:%s: " fmt, getpid(), __LINE__, __func__

#define SIZE(a) (sizeof a/sizeof *a)

#define ERR(fmt, ...) do{\
            fprintf(stderr, \
                    F(fmt": %s (errno = %d)\n"),\
                    ##__VA_ARGS__,\
                    strerror(errno),\
                    errno);\
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }while(0)

#define CLOSE(expr) do{\
            close(expr);\
            fprintf(stderr, \
                    F("close("#expr" === %d);\n"), \
                    (expr));\
    }while(0)

#define PIPE(var) do{\
            if(pipe(var)<0) ERR("pipe"); \
            fprintf(stderr,F("PIPE ==> %d, %d\n"), var[0], var[1]);\
    }while(0)

#define FORK() do{\
            if((res = fork()) < 0)ERR("fork");\
            fprintf(stderr,F("FORK ==> %d\n"), res);\
    }while(0)

#define DUP(expr1, expr2) do{\
            if((res = dup2(expr1, expr2)) < 0) ERR("dup");\
            fprintf(stderr,\
                    F("DUP("#expr1" === %d, "#expr2" === %d);\n"),\
                    (expr1), (expr2));\
    }while(0)


char * argv_DISK_DUMP[] = { "dd", "if=/dev/urandom", "ibs=1024", NULL };
char * argv_BASE64[] =    { "base64", NULL };
char * argv_HEAD[] =      { "head", "-n", "150", NULL };
char * argv_SORT[] =      { "sort", "-r", NULL };
char * argv_PR[] =        { "pr", NULL };

struct pipe_program {
 pid_t pid;
 pid_t ppid;
    char *pname;
    char **argv;
} pipe_programs[] = {

    0, 0, "dd", argv_DISK_DUMP,
    0, 0, "base64", argv_BASE64,
    0, 0, "head", argv_HEAD,
    0, 0, "sort", argv_SORT,
    0, 0, "pr", argv_PR,

};

/* size of last array */
size_t pipe_programs_n = SIZE(pipe_programs);

static size_t printus(int ix, struct pipe_program *p);
static pid_t WAIT(int *status);

int main()
{
    int res, i;
    struct pipe_program *p = pipe_programs;
    int input_fd = 0; /* first process is connected to standard input */
    static int pipe_fds[2] = { -1, -1 };

    for(i = 0; i < pipe_programs_n - 1; i++, p++) {

            PIPE(pipe_fds);

            FORK();

            if (res == 0) { /* child process, we have redirected nothing yet. */

                    p->pid = getpid();
                    p->ppid = getppid();

                    /* print who we are */
                    printus(i, p);

                    /* redirect input, if needed */
                    if (input_fd != 0) {
                            DUP(input_fd, 0);
                            CLOSE(input_fd); /* not used after redirection */
                    }

                    CLOSE(pipe_fds[0]); /* we don't use this */

                    /* and output */
                    DUP(pipe_fds[1], 1);
                    CLOSE(pipe_fds[1]);

                    execvp(p->pname, p->argv);

                    ERR("execvp: %s", p->pname);
                    /* NOTREACHED */

            }
            /* parent process */

            /* save pid to be used later */
            p->pid = res; /* we'll use it later */
            p->ppid = getpid();

            /* close unused pipe descriptor */
            CLOSE(pipe_fds[1]);

            /* if we have an old input_fd, then close it */
            if (input_fd) CLOSE(input_fd);

            /* ... and save pipe read descriptor */
            input_fd = pipe_fds[0];
    } /* for */

    /* now we have our input connected to the output of the last process */
    FORK();
    if (res == 0) { /* child, last process in the pipe */

            p->pid = getpid();
            p->ppid = getppid();

            /* print who we are */
            printus(i, p);

            /* redirect input */
            if (input_fd != 0) {
                    DUP(input_fd, 0);
                    CLOSE(input_fd); /* not used after_redirection */
            }

            /* this time no output redirection */

            execvp(p->pname, p->argv);

            ERR("execvp");
            /* NOTREACHED */
    }

    CLOSE(pipe_fds[1]);
    if (input_fd) CLOSE(input_fd);

    /* parent code... we did pipe_programs_n fork()'s so we
     * have to do pipe_programs_n wait()'s */
    int status;
    pid_t cld_pid;
    /* while we can wait for a child */
    while ((cld_pid = WAIT(&status)) > 0) {
            for (i = 0, p = pipe_programs; i < pipe_programs_n; i++, p++) {
                    if (cld_pid == p->pid) {
                            fprintf(stderr,
                                    F("Child finished: pid = %d\n"),
                                    cld_pid);
                            printus(i, p);
                            break;
                    }
            }
    } /* while */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static size_t printus(int ix, struct pipe_program *p)
{
    size_t res = 0;
    int j;
    static char buffer[1024];
    char *s = buffer;
    size_t bfsz = sizeof buffer;
    size_t n;

#define ACT() do{s+=n; bfsz-=n;}while(0)

    n = snprintf(s, bfsz,
            F("%d: pid = %d, ppid = %d, program = \"%s\": args = "),
            ix, p->pid, p->ppid, p->pname);
    ACT();
    for (j = 0; p->argv[j]; j++) {
            n = snprintf(s, bfsz,
                    "%s\"%s\"",
                    j ? ", " : "{",
                    p->argv[j]);
        ACT();
    }
    n = snprintf(s, bfsz, "};\n");
    ACT();
    fputs(buffer, stderr);

    return res;
}

static pid_t WAIT(int *status)
{
    pid_t res = wait(status);
    fprintf(stderr, F("WAIT() ==> %d\n"), res);
    return res;
}
```

you can get the whole program with the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:mojadita/pipe.git
```

beware that the program there is almost exactly equal, but some work has been done to facilitate the writing of different pipelines without having to touch several places in the main source file.  Edit the file `pipe.i` if you download the program from the git server and you want to modify the pipeline.  Then `make` and voilá!!! :)  The program has been tested on linux, freebsd and mac osx, so I think you'll have no problem to adapt it to your needs.  If you get it from the github, you'll also have a `Makefile`.

Comment: Thanks but in a loop of n pipes, it's going to create zombie and a massive number of fork no ?
Because this is just a portion of my code and I also don't want my program to exit when the command is finished. Thanks

Comment: To create n processes in unix, you need to do n forks, no other way.  What do you mean with a pipe? a pipe as I understand is a bunch of processes all of them linked by pipe objects.  Zombie processes are created **only** when they die (`exit(2)`), and their parent has not made a `wait(2)` for them yet.  As you have the parent finished, they get their parent id switched to `1` (init process) that is always making `wait` so you don't get many such zombies.... Zombie process is not something to be afraid of, so don't fear them, they won't eat your brain :)

Comment: As an illustration, follow the code (it's open source) that `bash(1)` uses to implement a pipe, and you'll see code similar to mine.  By the way, have you tested my code? because I have made the effort to test it for you, and it creates no zombies.

Comment: In my function, there is a while which do n-fork for the n-pipes. But I wait, with my wait(NULL) one by one, how can I do with your solution to do it in a while ?

Comment: I'm about to upload a solution for a general pipe chain.  The problem is that it is very easy to forget to close a file descriptor and then the process is engaged forever.... see my solution in the edit to this answer.

Comment: @Ogagal, now you have a full pipeline example with a middle process dying and finalizing all the pipeline (backwards and forwards)